# number of records per day using grails

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a **grails** application with a mysql database as the datasource. The mysql database is created and maintained by a third party. One of the tables `'visitinfo'` contains 2 columns consisting of the `'userid'` and `'logindatetime'`.

`userid` is of type TEXT and logindatetime is of type 'datetime'.

In order to access the above table `'visitinfo'`, I have created a domain class 'VisitInfo' and mapped it to the mysql database table by which my grails application can easily store as well as retrieve data from the database.

On one of the pages, I am required to show visitor information for the last 30 days. So basically I am looking out for a solution to get number of visitors per day for the last 30 days. Something like this:

```
21-Jan-2012 ------ 36
22-Jan-2012 ------ 85
23-Jan-2012 ------ 115
24-Jan-2012 ------ 236
etc.
```

Also please note, that if a userid `'williamp'` has 2 entries on a particular day, it should be counted as 2. So, am not looking out for uniqueness of users.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following hql query to match your requirement

```
VisitInfo.executeQuery("select logindatetime, count(*) from VisitInfo group by logindatetime")
```

Comment: It would be `group by logindatetime`

Comment: Since the logindatetime column is of type datetime, if I use group by logindatetime it groups according to a very small granular level like seconds depending on the number of entries in the table...

Comment: a wouraround would be to interate over each day of the last 30 day and excute the query for the particular day. at the end sum up the determined count for each day. e.g.

VisitInfo.executeQuery("select count(userid) from VisitInfo where longdatetiem between <starttime of day> and <endTime of day>")

Comment: @hitty5: Can't hit the database so many times as its on a remote box and performance is slow. Have to make the most in one call.

Comment: VisitInfo.executeQuery("select DAY(logindatetime), MONTH(logindatetime), YEAR(logindatetime), count(userid) from VisitInfo group by DAY(logindatetime), MONTH(logindatetime), YEAR(logindatetime)"); Maybe this query mathes your need. You have to restrict the time preriod with the where clause and sort the result on your side.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing at all about grails. The MySQL query to obtain the desired result is as follows:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(logindatetime,'%d-%m-%Y') dt
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM visitinfo
 GROUP 
    BY dt;
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the response. But i was looking out for a grails solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the countBy gorm method.

```
numLogins=VisitInfo.countByReleaseDateBetween(startOfDay,endOfDay)
```

This would need to be in a loop that calculates two date objects for each of the last 30 days. startOfDay would need a time value of 00:00:00:00 and endOfDay would need a time value of 23:59:00:00

Comment: Thanks for the response. Since my database is on a remote machine (not on same box as the grails app) calling the above method 30 times is giving me a response time of over a minute which is not acceptable as of now. Do you know of a solution in which I could make 1 database call and get the information as a list?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do it in one call. Since only the current day will have an updated result though you could cache the results for the previous 29 days.